# Connect To Docker Compose MongoDb Via Spring boot application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

My web app can't connect to the MongoDB container

here are my application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://mongo:27017
      host: mongo
      port: 27017
      database: my-db-name
```

and this is my Docker-Compose

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  java:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - shared-net

  mongo:
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    hostname: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    networks:
      - shared-net

networks:
  shared-net:
    driver: bridge
```

and this is the Dockerfile wrote for running java

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY ./code/lemon-backend/target/lemon-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "lemon-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I can't even build the application using these options
I get this exception:

`org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo:27017`

if possible try giving solutions with docker-compose, thanks

Comment: A common cause of this is the application starting up before the database is fully ready; while Compose will start the services in order it has know way of knowing when one is "ready".  If you re-run `docker-compose up` again, does it work after a minute or so?

Comment: no, it wont.i even tried ```docker-compose up -d db``` to run the db only and tring to run the application later.

Comment: in adition to that i have the ```depends_on``` property which makes the db service come first

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**OLD VERSION ANSWER**

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
older versions of MongoDB ignore this configuration in `application.properties`, proceed ahead & use the new solutions I added

---

This workaround is used for old versions of spring and mongo that ignore the normal configuration (other than uri)

. *I had a warning that this property cant be resolved
but hopefully, it worked :)*

```
dockerspring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://<your_mongodb_container_name>:27017/<name_of_your_db>
```

*the mongodb part is not changeable but mongo before the port number is actually the name of the container witch you have specified in your docker-compose*

---

**SPRING BOOT SOLUTION**

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: <mongo-db-container-name>
      port: <mongo-db-port>
      database: <database-name>
```

---

**DOCKER SOLUTION**

In Your Dockerfile Add This Option For Executing Java

```
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,”-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27017/name_of_your_db”, “-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom”,”-jar”,”/<name_of_your_app>.jar”]
```

---

**Linking Java And Mongo Containers + Giving Them Names**

here this is my final docker-compose.yml,
I hope that it helps you

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  java:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: java
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - shared-net
 
 mongo:
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - /home/sinoed/data/db:/data/db
    networks:
      - shared-net

networks:
  shared-net:
    driver: bridge
```

**Compare this version and the one specified in the question carefully**

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution! I had the same problem and fixed it by applying your suggestions. The only thing I would add to your solution is that the DB host (specified both in Dockerfile and in Java application url properties file) is not necessarily named "mongo"; if in your Docker compose, you named the container (container_name property) as mongo_whatever, then that is the host name you are going to have to use. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Im glad that this was usefull. Yeah you are right i have used container_name in docker-compose.yml but i've forgot to mention it in the answer. Thanks for mentioning it ill edit the answer.